# Python - Slow Execution of Stored Procedure in a Loop

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm writing a python script which connects with Oracle DB. I'm collecting specific Reference ID into a variable and then executing a Stored Procedure in a For Loop. It's working fine but its taking very long time to complete.

Here's a code:

```
sql = f"SELECT STATEMENT"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    
    for i in result:
        cursor.callproc('DeleteStoredProcedure', [i[0]])
        print("Deleted:", i[0])
```

The first SQL SELECT Statement collect around 600 Ref IDs but its taking around 3 mins to execute Stored Procedure which is very long if we have around 10K or more record.

BTW, the Stored Procedure is configured to delete rows from three different tables based on the reference ID. And its running quickly from Oracle Toad.

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Your first query could be tuned a bit with `arraysize`, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html if you're using the latest driver, or https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html if you're still using cx_Oracle.  But overall, follow the suggested answer and do all the work in one stored procedure or anonymous PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could create just one stored procedure that execute the `SELECT` statement and do what ever `DeleteStoredProcedure` does.

Or, you can use threads to execute every stored procedure:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html